# Is there a measure of "indefiniteness" of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, finite-element-method

#### Question

Is there a measure of the "indefiniteness" of a matrix? And what constitutes a "highly indefinite" matrix?

#### Explanation

I have to solve a linear system computationally, obtained from a multiphysics problem, using the Finite Element Method. But in order to correctly setup the solver I want to use (Pardiso), I have to know whether or not the matrix is "highly indefinite" or just indefinite.

### The linear system

The equation can be written as
$$\mathbf{K}\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{b}$$

where the matrix $\mathbf{K}$ is square and non-singular and can be extended to
$$\mathbf{K}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{A}&\mathbf{C}\\\mathbf{C}^t&\mathbf{B}\end{bmatrix}$$

where $\mathbf{A}$ is square and positive-definite, $\mathbf{B}$ is diagonal and negative-definite, and $\mathbf{C}$ is rectangular.

Without preconditioning, the values in $\mathbf{A}$ have an order of about $10^{10}$, the values in $\mathbf{B}$ have an order of about $10^{-9}$ and the values in $\mathbf{C}$ have an order of about $10^1$.

BUT I can perform left/right diagonal preconditioning to significantly improve the condition number of $\mathbf{K}$ (I imagine that the measure of indefiniteness takes the matrix conditioning into account?).

Answer (score 0):

The only answer I have found is a brief mention in an article by Michele Benzi *et. al.* [1]

> [...], the matrix $\mathcal{A}$ is *highly indefinite*, in the sense that **it has many eigenvalues of both signs**.

Where $\mathcal{A}$ is
$$\mathcal{A}=\begin{bmatrix}A & B\\ B^T &-C\end{bmatrix}$$

[1] Michele Benzi, Gene H. Golub and Jörg Liesen. *Numerical Solution of saddle point problems* (2005). Acta Numerica, v. 14, pp. 1–137. Doi 10.1017/S0962492904000212.